# How to get SLIME to autocomplete symbols from loaded other packages?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I think this used to work out of the box in Emacs 23, but in 24 it doesn't.

So, suppose I have Alexandria package loaded with Quicklisp. If I run `(apropos "curry")` in the REPL, for example, it finds the function definition, similarly, if I run `(describe 'curry)` etc. But SLIME refuses to autocomplete `(cur|` (point is shown by pipe) to anything.

How to tell SLIME where to look for sources / what is it missing?

**EDIT:**

Also, if I do <kbd>,</kbd>`in-package`<kbd>RET</kbd>ALEXANDRIA<kbd>RET</kbd> it will autocomplete, but I hoped it would autocomplete for any loaded package w/o me having to specify what package to look in. Or is there no other way?

Comment: How about "`ale` `TAB` `:cu` `TAB`", using the fact `curry` is exported from `alexandria`? In addition, `(describe 'curry)` just displays information about the symbol in the current package, not all symbols named `curry` in any package, at least in SBCL 1.0.55.

Comment: There are several completion styles: [Completion commands](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Completion.html) and [ac-slime](https://github.com/purcell/ac-slime). But, as far as I know, they don't behave as you wish. I think that the common workflow is to define your own package that `:use` or `:import-from` other packages, set the current package to it, and then spend most of your time in it. Naturally, the used or imported symbols can be completed without the package prefix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to do this in SLIME. I'm not sure it would be practical to use but it should be feasible to implement this by looking at how completion and apropos are implemented and mix them up in a new function. Bonus points for a customize-var to toggle completion style.

https://github.com/slime/slime